# Suppression of JSESSIONID cookie with Logback dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, logback

I want to ensure that JSESSIONID cookies are never created, from my understanding this can easily be done by setting `SessionCreationPolicy` to Stateless, for example

```
public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Order(1)
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

However, as soon at I add Logback dependencies to my Maven script, the JSESSIONID cookie seems to be getting created again, for example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way to explicitly override whatever the Logback dependencies are doing to re-enable session management?

My full code example is available at https://github.com/vicsz/demo-web-app

Comment: Do you want logback-access in there? According the docs it must be installed at container level, not web-app level.

Comment: @holmis83 -- not quite sure what you mean , but yes I do want logging via Logback